# Taking the infinite-volume limit of a lattice fermion in different ways: does this give all unitarily inequivalent Hilbert-space representations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

When the quantum field theory of a free fermion field is formulated on a finite lattice, the Hilbert space is finite-dimensional. The "spectrum condition" that we normally require in QFT is automatically satisfied: the spectrum of the Hamiltonian has a lower bound simply because the Hilbert space only has a finite number of dimensions.

We can give the lowest-energy state any energy we want just by adding a constant term $E_0$ to the Hamiltonian ("constant" = proportional to the identity operator), but if we want to preserve the spectrum condition in the infinite-volume limit, then we need to make $E_0$ depend on the lattice parameters in a way that keeps the energy of the lowest-energy state finite in that limit. Applying the field operators to this state generates a complete Hilbert-space representation that satisfies the spectrum condition.

If we're not trying to enforce the spectrum condition, then we can take the infinite-volume limit in other ways. For example, we could make $E_0$ depend on the lattice parameters in a way that keeps the energy of the *highest*-energy state finite, and use that state to generate a Hilbert-space representation. Then the Hamiltonian will have a finite *upper* bound — the opposite of what we normally require in QFT, but still mathematically legitimate. Or we could choose $E_0$ to keep the energy of some intermediate-energy state finite. Then the Hamiltonian can be unbounded on both ends.

The upshot of all this is that we can get many different unitarily inequivalent representations of the same set of field operators just by taking the infinite-volume limit in different ways. Most of these Hilbert-space representations violate the physically-motivated spectrum condition, but they're all mathematically legitimate.

**Question:** Does this approach give *every* unitarily inequivalent Hilbert-space representation of the given free fermion field? Or do other Hilbert-space representations exist that are not unitarily equivalent to any of these?

Motive: This question came up while thinking about how the choice of Hilbert-space representation might affect 't Hooft anomalies.